# Backbone.js route interceptor

Tags: backbone.js, routes, interceptor

I have main app with subapps:
main_app
 |-mainRouter.js
|-sub_app
    |-subAppRouter.js

subAppRouter.js extends mainRouter.js. subAppRouter.js has handler for route (e.g. /app1/item/). I have no access to subAppRouter.
**Here is what I need:**
In mainRouter I want to create routing that will handle all URL's from all apps. 
It should handle route , make some check and in one case it should continue firing handler from subAppRouter for that url, else it should make redirect (e.g. /app2/somepage).

Could someone helps me with finding the best solution how to do it?
In other words: how to realize interceptor pattern via router in backbone?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

i will rephrase your question in points

1- you have a main router for common routes

2- you have a specialized router for some app routes

3- you need your main router to choose weather to handle the route of just forward it to sub router

to achieve this i suggest the following

1- create the main router , extending Backbone.Router

```
var mainRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes:{
        'index':'loadIndex',
        //other common app routes......
    },
    loadIndex: function(){
        //code to load index
    }
});
```

2- then define the sub router for app,extending the main router, but notice how routes is defined

```
var subAppRouter = mainRouter.extend({
    initialize: function(){
        // here we will extend the base routes to not lose default routing, and add app special routing
        _.extend(this.routes, {
           'subApp/index': 'subAppIndex'
       });
    },
    subAppIndex: function(){
         // code to load sub app index
    },
});
```

then you can use the sub router which will contains the base routing also

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://www.geekdave.com/2012/04/05/module-specific-subroutes-in-backbone/) is a good article about subrouting. This works perfect for me.

Include subroute js lib in your project:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="backbone.subroute.min.js"></script>
```

HTML body example:

```
<a href="#app1/">App1</a>
<a href="#app2">App2</a>
<div class="app">
</div>
```

JS Code example:

```
var MyApp = {};
MyApp.App1 = {
    Router: Backbone.SubRoute.extend({
        routes: {
            "": "init",
            "sub1": "sub1"
        },
        init: function  () {
            console.log("app1");
            $(".app").html($("<h1 />", {text: "App1"}));
            $(".app").append($("<a/>", {href: "#app1/sub1", text: "sub1"}));
        },
        sub1: function  () {
            console.log("sub1");
            $(".app").append($("<h2 />", {text: "sub1"}));
        }
    })
};
MyApp.Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
    initialize: function  () {
        if(!MyApp.Routers){
            MyApp.Routers = {};
        }
    },
    routes: {
        "app1/*subroute": "invokeApp1Router",
        "app2": "app2"
    },
    invokeApp1Router: function  (subroute) {
        if(!MyApp.Routers.App1){
            MyApp.Routers.App1 = new MyApp.App1.Router("app1/");
        }               
    },

    app2: function  () {
        console.log("app2");
        $(".app").html($("<h1 />", {text: "App2"}));
    }
});

$(document).ready(function  () {
    new MyApp.Router();
    Backbone.history.start();
})
```